# Sylius custom model with images

Tags: php, image, upload, e-commerce, sylius

I followed those recipes to:

1. [Create a custom model](http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html)
2. [Add images to this custom model](http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/images/images-on-entity.html)

I detected some things that don't happens like the recipes say, but once I have my custom model working, with the forms, the grid, the validation, the form extended to allow upload images... I got this error after send the form of creating a new object:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO app_designer_image (type, path, owner_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["avatar", null, 2]:
```

I can't find the way to upload an image. Following the recipe, I defined a Image Upload Service listener, listening to the `sylius.designer.pre_create` and `sylius.designer.pre_update` but those events are never triggered, and when the image is going to be persisted, always fail because the path is not defined...

Any clue of what can be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. There was a misconfiguration for the event listener, I attach the listener to the wrong event.

My mistake was follow strictly all the steps in this [recipe](http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/images/images-on-entity.html). The problem is that the recipe is based on an **extended version** of an existing model, and the name of the events for a custom model is prepended by `app.` instead of `sylius.`.

So, the event in the example is `sylius.shipping_method.pre_create` and mine is not `sylius.designer.pre_create` but `app.designer.pre_create`.

Once I fixed this everything starts to work as expected.